# Do I need DispatchQueue.main to update UI after an Alamofire request?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, grand-central-dispatch

I'm following a tutorial about working with `REST/web requests`. In the tutorial, we're working towards a Pokedex app where we fetch Pokemon details from an API using `Alamofire`, and then displaying that data in our UIs.

Here's the related code:

```
typealias DownloadComplete = (Bool) -> ()

// Model class
func downloadPokemonDetails(completed: @escaping DownloadComplete)
    {
        Alamofire.request(_pokemonURL).responseJSON { (response) in
            var success = true
            if let jsonData = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String, Any>
            {
                // parse the json here
                ...
            }
            else
            {
                success = false
            }
            completed(success)
        }
    }

// Controller class
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pokemon.downloadPokemonDetails(completed: { (success) in
            if success
            {
                self.updateUI()
            }
            else
            {
                print("FAILED: TO PARSE JSON DATA")
            }
        })
    }

func updateUI()
{
    attackLbl.text = pokemon.attack
    defenseLbl.text = pokemon.defense
    heightLbl.text = pokemon.height
    weightLbl.text = pokemon.weight
}
```

Now my question is: shouldn't we use `DispatchQueue.main.` and update the UI there like so?

```
pokemon.downloadPokemonDetails(completed: { (success) in
            if success
            {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.updateUI()
                }
            }
```

The tutorial left it out and I'm not sure if `DispatchQueue` is needed here to update the UI. I know that updating UI in a background thread is bad practice so if anyone can shed some light on whether using DispatchQueue here to get the main thread is necessary or not, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Did you have a look at the [Alamofire Readme](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)? – "Response handlers by default are executed on the main dispatch queue. ...."

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the comment. I haven't actually but does that mean I don't need the DispatchQueue.main when updating the UI anymore in this case? I'm still new to this stuff.

Comment: You do not need. You can check it by `dispatch_get_current_queue() == dispatch_get_main_queue()`

Comment: Thanks @NeilGaliaskarov for confirming. I would like to use the snippet you posted to verify but `dispatch_get_current_queue()` is already deprecated and I can't use it to find out for myself. I can't seem to find the replacement of that.

Comment: `if Thread.isMainThread {
    print("Main Thread")
}`

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the code! This is going to be handy for debugging "am I on the main thread" questions like the one I faced above. I can now confirm that Alamofire's request handler is on the main thread.

Comment: to make Alamofire working out in main thread you can using the following:


'let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.cnoon.response-queue", qos: .background, attributes: [.concurrent])
                
                
                Alamofire.request(_url, method: myHTTPMethod, parameters: self.Parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default , headers: Headers).responseJSON(queue: queue, options: .allowFragments) { (response) in
                     completion(self.getResponse(response: response))
                }'

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If one does not want to read the whole comments section, I am posting here it as answer.
Firstly, read [Alamofire docs](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire), which clearly states: ***"Response handlers by default are executed on the main dispatch queue."***

It means, you can call any UI related code in response block. If you still feel uncomfortable to rely on 3rd party lib doc, you can check by executing this `swift3` snippet:

```
if Thread.isMainThread { 
   print("Main Thread") 
}
```

**xcode 9**

Starting from **xcode 9** there is a built-in `Main Thread Checker` which detects invalid use of AppKit, UIKit, and other APIs from a background thread. `Main Thread Checker` is automatically enabled when you run your app with the Xcode debugger.

If any part of your project contains invalid UI calls from background thread, you will see the following:

[image]

** *Demonstrated in Xcode Version 9.1 (9B55)*