# Data passing from model not showing in UI after using Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, networking, alamofire

So I have created a model to download data (images, title, desc) using alamofire. But having problem to pass the data and update it in the **viewController**. If I put the functions in viewController's **viewDidLoad** then it is working very fine. But I want to use the MVC model. Here is the code for the model:

```
class PageControllerView {
    var _titleName : String!
    var _titleDesc : String!
    var _image : UIImage!

    var titleName : String {
        if _titleName == nil {
            _titleName = ""
            print("titlename is nil")
        }
        return _titleName
    }

    var titleDesc : String {
        if _titleDesc == nil {
            print("tittledesc is nile")
            _titleDesc = ""
        }
        return _titleDesc
    }

    var image : UIImage {
        if _image == nil {
            print("Image view is nill")
            _image = UIImage(named: "q")
        }
        return _image
    }

    func getPageControllerData(_ page : Int) {
        Alamofire.request("\(BASE_URL)movie/now_playing?api_key=\(API_KEY)&language=en-US&page=1").responseJSON { (response) in

            if let JSON = response.result.value {

                if let json = JSON as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                    if let results = json["results"] as? [Dictionary<String, Any>] {
                        if let overview = results[page]["overview"] as? String {
                            self._titleDesc = overview
                        }
                        if let releaseDate = results[page]["release_date"] as? String {
                            if let title = results[page]["title"] as? String {
                                let index = releaseDate.index(releaseDate.startIndex, offsetBy: 4)
                                self._titleName = "\(title) (\(releaseDate.substring(to: index)))"
                            }
                        }
                        if let image_url = results[page]["poster_path"] as? String{

                            Alamofire.request("\(BASE_URL_IMAGE)\(IMAGE_SIZE)\(image_url)").downloadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                                print(progress.fractionCompleted)

                            }).responseData(completionHandler: { (response) in
                                print("completed downloading")
                                if let imageData = response.result.value {
                                    self._image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                                }
                            })

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    }


}
```

And this is the viewControllers code (It is working fine but i want to pass the model. The alamofirefuntion is also present in the viewcontroller):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            print("viewdidload")
            getPageControllerData(13)
            self.updatePageControllerUI()
        }

    func updatePageControllerUI() {
            pageControllerMovieLabel.text = pageControllerView.titleName
            pageControllerSubLabel.text = pageControllerView.titleDesc
            pageControlImageView.image = pageControllerView.image

        }

func getPageControllerData(_ page : Int) {
        Alamofire.request("\(BASE_URL)movie/now_playing?api_key=\(API_KEY)&language=en-US&page=1").responseJSON { (response) in

            if let JSON = response.result.value {

                if let json = JSON as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                    if let results = json["results"] as? [Dictionary<String, Any>] {
                        if let overview = results[page]["overview"] as? String {
                            self.pageControllerSubLabel.text = overview
                        }
                        if let releaseDate = results[page]["release_date"] as? String {
                            if let title = results[page]["title"] as? String {
                                let index = releaseDate.index(releaseDate.startIndex, offsetBy: 4)
                                self.pageControllerMovieLabel.text = "\(title) (\(releaseDate.substring(to: index)))"
                            }
                        }
                        if let image_url = results[page]["poster_path"] as? String{

                            Alamofire.request("\(BASE_URL_IMAGE)\(IMAGE_SIZE)\(image_url)").downloadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                                print(progress.fractionCompleted)
                            }).responseData(completionHandler: { (response) in

                                if let imageData = response.result.value {
                                     self.pageControlImageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                                }
                            })

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

My question is how to pass the model so that i can use like this, by using the  **PageControllerView** object.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("viewdidload")
        pageControllerView.getPageControllerData(13)
        self.updatePageControllerUI()
    }
```

Now I have checked that this code works but the image is still not shown at firstgo since it has not been downloaded completely but the title and description is showing.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("viewdidload")
        pageControllerView.getPageControllerData(4)


    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.updatePageControllerUI()
    }
```

Comment: Are you displaying it on the main queue ? DispatchQueue.main.async {

}

Comment: Should I ? Doesn't alamofire takes care of it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41135766/do-i-need-dispatchqueue-main-to-update-ui-after-an-alamofire-request

NVM

Comment: OT: Why is your model called PageController*View*? Also consider https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide

Comment: @RaphaelP. Care to show how it is done with this code ?